# How to use a discrete colorscale in plotly scattergeo usa map

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to use a discrete colorscale when I'm using plotly (in python). I need a discrete colorscale as some values I'm plotting for specific cities are way too large as compared to all others, hence a discrete color scale would help me visualize all values with ease. Here's an example to explain my situation better:
I have a dataset that contains details about certain events by city (in USA). 
The event occurred in New York City 50000 times whereas in other cities in the USA, the same event occurred less that 1000 times. When I use a continuous colorscale, all other city values fall to the low end and NYC is the only value which utilizes the color at the top of the colorscale.

Thanks for your help in advance!
Best Regards,
Rishabh

Answer (score 1):

For 10 different cluster ids for several stores, that's how I generated 10 discrete custom color scales:

```
import matplotlib

def matplotlib_to_plotly(cmap, pl_entries):
# Converts matplotlib colormap to plotly colormap. It also shuffles the color map

    h = 1.0/(pl_entries)
    pl_colorscale = []
    c_order = h * np.arange(pl_entries+1)
    c_order_shuffled = c_order.copy()
    # Shuffles the colormap
    np.random.shuffle(c_order_shuffled)
    for i in range(pl_entries):
        C = map(np.uint8, np.array(cmap(c_order_shuffled[i])[:3])*255)
        pl_colorscale.append([c_order[i], 'rgb'+str((C[0], C[1], C[2]))])
        # To have clear boundaries between colors in the colorbar
        if i < (pl_entries):
             pl_colorscale.append([c_order[i+1], 'rgb'+str((C[0], C[1], C[2]))])
    return pl_colorscale

# Sets the colormap of your choice 
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')
# Passes the number of distinct colors you need to generate. In this case we have 10 cluster ids in stores_info_df
custom_colorscale = matplotlib_to_plotly(cmap, stores_info_df['CLUSTER_ID'].max())
custom_colorscale
```

[image]

Then, I used the above colorscale in the plot function:

```
def visualize_geo_store_clusters(stores_info_df, fig_name='store_similarity_US_map', cluster_id = 'CLUSTER_ID'):

    max_cluster_id = stores_info_df[cluster_id].max()

    data = [ dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = stores_info_df['LONGTITUDE'],
        lat = stores_info_df['LATITUDE'],
        text = stores_info_df['TEXT'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(
            colorscale= custom_colorscale, 
            cmin = stores_info_df[cluster_id].min(),
            color = stores_info_df[cluster_id],
            cmax = max_cluster_id,
            colorbar = dict(
                title = 'Cluster ID',
                titleside = 'top',
                tickmode = 'array',
                tickvals =  np.arange(1, max_cluster_id+1),
                ticktext = np.arange(1, max_cluster_id+1),
                #ticks = 'outside',
            )

        ))]

     layout = dict(
        title = 'Similarity between Stores',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            projection=dict( type='albers usa' ),
            showland = True,
            landcolor = "rgb(250, 250, 250)",
            subunitcolor = "rgb(217, 217, 217)",
            countrycolor = "rgb(217, 217, 217)",
            countrywidth = 0.5,
            subunitwidth = 0.5
        ),
    )

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

It generates the following plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's not obvious why @Sahar's answer works, you find the solution [here](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale):

> *You can create a discrete color scale, with discontinuous color, by **setting the same reference point twice in a row**.*

Here I give an example how the creation of a continuous colorscale differs from a discrete one.

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
nc = len(colors)
colorscale_continuous = tuple(zip(np.linspace(0, 1, nc), colors))
colorscale_discrete = sorted(
    tuple(zip(np.linspace(0, 1 - 1/nc + 1e-6, nc), colors)) +
    tuple(zip(np.linspace(1/nc, 1, nc), colors)))
```

(the factor `1e-6` is simply to assert a correct sorting)

Finally, to center the colorbar ticks on each discrete color (note that those are vertically offset/misaligned as shown in @Sahar's answer), provide the following parameter to `colorbar`:

```
tickvals=np.linspace(1/nc/2, 1 - 1/nc/2, nc) * (nc - 1)
```